# Dynamically created html elements using aura:html removing some attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

The code I am trying is-

```
var newComponents = [];
newComponents.push(["aura:html", {
                                    "tag": "a",
                                    "body": "click",
                                    "HTMLAttributes": {
                                        "href": '#id=123',
                                        "onclick": "alert(\"test\")"
                                    }
                                }]);
```

When I add the components using $A.createComponents method, it only renders the href attribute, but not onclick or press as well. I tried with class, id attributes also, they are getting rendered successfully. Any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `onclick` needs to be a reference to a controller method.

Try something like:

```
"onclick" : component.getReference("c.yourHandleClickMethod");
```

The reason that the `onclick` handler is removed is because it's treated like any other markup that you add - any directly executed javascript is removed at compile time.

Comment: That's it! Just awesome!

Comment: Glad to help :)